# Java - Execute Excel.exe from code in windows

Tags: java, windows, excel

I've develped a software which at a certain point needs to open an existing excel file, the file is choosen by the user.

Here the method:

```
private void openChoiceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Open file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        //osName = osName.toLowerCase();

        fd.setLocation(600,200);
        fd.setFile("*.xlsx");
        fd.setVisible(true);

        String dir = fd.getDirectory();
        String fileName = fd.getFile();
        String path = dir + fileName;

        File file = new File(path);
        if(file != null){
            try {
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        if(osName.equals("Linux")){
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("libreoffice --calc "+ path);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Errore nell'apertura del file: " +ex);
            }
        }else{
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\EXCEL.EXE "+ path);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Errore nell'apertura del file: " +ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

The software needs to work both on Linux and Windows so I've taken the path of the executable in function of the OS

On Linux all works fine!

On Windows I got an error:

> Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" Create process error=5  Acess denied

I need only to run excel, but I'm not figuring out how can I resolve this because `C:\Program Files (x86)` is not available to the application

Comment: Does the user running the Java have the right to acces that Folder and start applications?

Comment: Can you manually run this through CMD `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\EXCEL.EXE "+ path`

Comment: Yes I'm able to access and run that .exe both from ui and CDM

Comment: Finally I resolved it, there was a problem of translation, in CMD paths are in the english version of directories, and the path of .exe file must be surrounded with " "